# Accessing Symlink folder in ~/Sites folder on Mac (Web Sharing)

Tags: macos, apache2, localhost, dropbox, symlink

I have a local development environment setup on my mac and I am having permission issues accessing a folder in my ~/Sites directory.

Essentially I have Folder A in my Dropbox folder.

I created a SymLink of Folder A to my ~/Sites folder

`ln -s ~/Sites ~/Dropbox/FolderA`

When I try to access Folder A like so: `localhost/~username/FolderA`

The page says `You don't have permission to access /~username/FolderA on this server`

Can someone help me figure out this problem. When I do the same thing on MAMP I don't have this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Go on `private/etc/apache2/users/`, edit your `usernamefile.conf`, add to the **Options** line, the option **SymLinksIfOwnerMatch**, don't use **FollowSymLinks** if the directory contains important personal files, if for example the dir that you want link is are under your Documents or Dropbox.
Remember that the directory linked by your symbolic link must have 755 permission, and so her parents!
Let's suppose you have `/Users/foo/Dropbox/MySites/BarSite`, both Users, foo, Dropbox, MySites, BarSite must be 755.